# Is it possible to have different ID attributes of same html element on different systems/browsers?

Tags: javascript, html, dom, web-applications

I am surfing a website (Oracle Fusion Application). For any html element, suppose the id attribute is "_FOd578fh:6_ge".
When I check the same website on different systems (windows 10) and different browsers, the Id is same. That's what we expect, right?

But in a particular system (windows 10), the same element's Id is changed to "pt:1_FOd578fh:6_ge", in all the browsers.

`<a id="pt:1_FOd578fh:6_ge" href="something">Some text</a>`

What could be the possible reason for this strange behavior?

P.s: I tried after removing the extensions, as well as re-installing the browser too. Nothing worked.

Comment: The application can make up id values according to whatever rules it wants. What difference does it make? What do you actually want to achieve?

Comment: I'm running a selenium test automation for that website, and it is failing on this particular system because of different Ids.

Comment: Well as I said the target application is free to invent completely random id values, or anything else for that matter.

Comment: okay, I understand! But why this change is happening only on one particular system?

Comment: Please don't tag-spam your questions. What does any of this have to do with "oracle"?

Comment: The error is coming on Oracle Fusion web application. It may not be directly related to Oracle, but it do has some strings attached to oracle. Don't you agree?  Anyways, thanks for edit! :) @mathguy

Comment: The “oracle” tag (perhaps misnamed) is specifically for Oracle Database, not for all Oracle products, of which there may be hundreds. The tag is described if you hover your mouse over it.